# Install tizen app on TV through network - connection manager

Tags: android, networking, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, television

I am trying to install tizen app on real TV to test it. It works fine on emulator but cant install it on TV. I follow this steps https://www.samsungdforum.com/TizenGuide/tizen3511/index.html but in my connection explorer i get something like [this.](https://www.samsungdforum.com/upload_files/images/WebEditor/20150713024605.jpg) I found related error [here](https://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/3ad8bd6023af18a7?forumID=70aee396cd7cc734) but not found any useful answer.

My TV is in developer mode, I inserted my PC IP, rebooted, TV and PC are on same network but still cant connect it.

ps: Installation with USB is not an option because my TV firmware does not supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Updating TV firmware solved the issue. Firmware should be more than 1400 (my version was 12xx). 
To upgrade firmware download drivers from official site and install it through USB (after completed installation reboot is needed).